# Передача данных через javascript на другой сайт

Tags: javascript

Как передать данные на другой сайт при помощи javascript?

Смысл действия такой же как у, например, счетчика яндекс:

Есть сайты aaa.com и bbb.ru. На сайте bbb.ru имеется некий скрипт, который в результате своей работы выдает две переменные. Назовем их X и Y. Необходимо отправить эти переменные на сайт aaa.com и там записать в БД. При этом сделать это надо без участия пользователя. Человек зашел на сайт - данные ушли.

Как это реализовать?

Comment: Попахивает попыткой кражи личных данных пользователя.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

на aaa.com в нужный вам момент вызываете что то типа такого:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'bbb.ru/api/postMethod',
    data: {x: 100, y: 500}
});
```

на bbb.ru реализуете вебапишник, который принимает ваш запрос.

Comment: А можно чуть подробнее? Или дайте ссылку где почитать о такой передаче...

Comment: @anj1817 подробнее так: на сайте `bbb.ru` с помощью сервера генерируешь страницу, которая отдает данные в виде `json`. С сайта `aaa.ru` обращаешься к данной странице сайта `bbb.ru` и парсишь данные. Причем если обращаться через аякс, то `bbb.ru` должен отдавать данные в виде `jsonp` и аякс должен быть соответствующий.... а если `json`, то `bbb.ru` должен доверять сайту `aaa.ru` иначе не выйдет ничего из за same origin policy

Comment: @anj1817, во-первых прочитайте про same origin policy: http://learn.javascript.ru/same-origin-policy, чтобы понять что все не очень просто.

Как вообще сейчас организованы кросдоменные коммуникации описано на протяжении раздела про ajax того же учебника

Answer (score 2):

на сайте *b* в коде страницы упоминаете:

1. нужные данные
2. url скрипта, находящегося на сайте *a*

скрипт (с сайта *a*), отрабатывая, извлекает эти данные из кода страницы и формирует запрос к сайту *a*, в котором и передаёт эти самые данные.