# Передать переменные из javascript в src

Tags: javascript

Всем привет. Задача вот такая попалась.
Есть некий javascript, он выдает две переменные:

```
<script>
var a = 7, 
var b = 8, 
</script>
<script src="http://yyyy.ru/sc.js?alpha=a&beta=b"></script>
```

Эти две переменные надо передать сайту yyyy.ru. Хитрый план заключается в том, чтобы отправить их туда при помощи обращения к скрипту, но как показывает практика такое не возможно сделать просто так. Значения переменных а и b не передаются в адрес скрипта. Закрался вполне резонный вопрос, а можно ли такое утворить в принципе?

Comment: Для начала стоит убрать синтаксические ошибки в скрипте. А потом подумать.

Comment: Можно. http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/460447/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7-javascript-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82#comment502441_460447

Comment: @АлексейШиманский через аякс получается как-то слишком сложно. Нельзя ли просто подменить данные в строке запроса другого скрипта? Грубо говоря, чтобы при запросе скрипта вместо a становилось 7, а вместо b 8. Мне кажется было бы красивее, чем обращаться к сайту приемнику, потом с него аяксом парсить данные с сайта донора. На данный момент я схему, которую предлагают по ссылке так вижу.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно попробовать так:

```
<script>
    var a = 7, 
        b = 8, 
        script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = "http://yyyy.ru/sc.js?alpha="+a+"&beta="+b+"";
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
</script>
```

Comment: гениально! Все прекрасно работает! Но не могли бы вы просветить еще чуть-чуть меня и дать информацию, где можно почитать подробнее о том, что происходит в этом коде?

Comment: Создаем элемент `script`, устанавливаем для него нужный нам атрибут `src` → вставляем созданный элемент в `head` документа, браузер видит, что dom изменился и перерисовывает страницу с уже готовым  `script` и обращается к нему. + вам лучше что-то отдавать на запрос, чтобы не было ошибки при паркинге или вообще ничего)